# VPNの動作確認のために中国からの接続が成功するかどうか確認する方法

Tags: vpn

中国に旅行するさいにVPNを使ってFacebookやTwitterにアクセスしたいのですが、OpenVPNをサクラのVPSにインストールし国内からの接続を確認、そのあとに中国の知人に試してみてもらったところ接続が失敗しました。

中国から接続した時にVPNが使えるかどうかを日本国内から確認する方法、もしくはサービスなどありますか？

Comment: 中国からVPNは難しいですよ。一旦接続ができても、数日後にはできなくなるなんてことはザラです。商用のプロバイダーは中国政府が発行する証明書がないとVPNが張れません。`確証はありませんが`、証明書チェーンの上位に政府が絡んでいて、グレートファイヤーウォールで復号化できない通信は遮断するなどの措置が取られている気がします。

Comment: そうなんですね、以前はVPNを使えば良かったときいていたので規制が厳しくなったのでしょうか。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Aliyun](http://www.aliyun.com/?lang=en) など、中国国内の IaaS で AWS の EC2 相当を利用するというのはどうでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ自分には接続確認のために設定を行うハードルの高さが割に合わないので知人に頼る方法にとどまろうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can configure the VPN, if you want to take it easier, you can use plugin like`红杏` in chrome browser, but you need to pay the cost. This plugin can only be used in PC.
p.s, there are many VPN on Internet, if you just want to use Facebook in mobile phone, try it, it's easy.

---

日本語訳:

確実かつ簡単にVPNを構築したいなら「红杏」のようなChromeブラウザのプラグインがあります。ただ、コストがかかります。このプラグインはPC用です。

p.s
インターネットには多くのVPNがあります。もしあなたがモバイルでFacebookを使いたいのであればそれを試してみてください。簡単ですよ。

Comment: Maybe your answer is valid as an answer.
However, you won't translate to Japanese.
Is sorry when this it is difficult to read it is translating.

Comment: 討議中の英語の質問に対しての投票を促すためにお礼を設定しました。
荒っぽい方法ですが、メタまで目を通す人は少ないのでご理解いただければと思います。
ささやかですが、迷惑をお掛けしたお礼をさせていただきます。