# インターネットが規制された環境を手元で再現できるか

Tags: network

ローカルのネットワーク環境において、インターネットが規制された環境を想定して、 VPN サーバーを構築したいと考えています。

具体的に想定している規制の内容はひとまず以下です:

- DNS が利用できない
- 特定 IP に接続できない

これを、VPN クライアントを用いて、ネットワーク通信をすべて外部 VPN サーバーを経由することで、通信が行えることを確認したい、が目的です。

質問:

- このような環境を再現して VPN 経由インターネット接続を検証したいです。環境を再現するのに適したツールなどはありますか。

関連:

- [VPNの動作確認のために中国からの接続が成功するかどうか確認する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12225/754) : 中国で VPN 接続ができることを検証するにはどうしたらいいか、という質問ですが、中国の IaaS を使え、が答えになっています。この質問は、中国での接続検証が最大目的ではなく、ローカルにそのような規制された環境を組み立てる技術的な方法はあるか、が主な関心ごとなので、ひとまず重複ではないと考えます。

Comment: 「規制」というのは、どのようにして実装(実現)するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Ciscoルータ(米国Cisco社のルータ)などを使ってインターネットとローカルネットワークを接続します。
ルータで接続を拒否するIPを設定できますから、特定のIPやDNSのIPに接続できない状況が実現できます。極端な話、VPNサーバのIP以外とは通信できなくすることも可能です。

Ciscoルータでなくても(他社製品でも)かまわないのですが、Ciscoは世界最大のネットワーク機器メーカーで製品のバリエーションが非常に豊富ですし、シスコ技術者認定資格のテキストなど資料類の入手が容易です。